# sum column by ID

Tags: r, sum

I have a data frame like this one with several rows for the same subject and with different durations :

```
ID                Duration        
1                  10             
2                  15
2                  10
3                  2
3                  5
3                  6
```

I would like to sum up all the durations per subject and put it in a new column to get a data frame like this one:

```
ID                Duration          Sum_duration
1                  10                     10
2                  15                     25
2                  10                     25
3                  2                       13
3                  5                       13
3                  6                       13
```

I thought of using these functions:
`df%>%group_by(id)` and `colSums`

but I don't know how to use them in my case.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Sum_duration = sum(Duration))
     ID Duration   sum
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1       10    10
2     2       15    25
3     2       10    25
4     3        2    13
5     3        5    13
6     3        6    13
```

**Data**

```
df = data.frame('ID' = c(1,2,2,3,3,3), "Duration" = c(10,15,10,2,5,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ave`

```
df$Sum_duration=ave(df$Duration,df$ID,FUN=sum)

  ID Duration Sum_duration
1  1       10           10
2  2       15           25
3  2       10           25
4  3        2           13
5  3        5           13
6  3        6           13
```